# cannot expose specific Nodeport via kubectl

Tags: kubectl

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose
Does not have required documentation

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort --port=8080 --target-port=30006
service/hello-minikube exposed

$ kubectl get svc 
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
hello-minikube   NodePort    10.110.117.25    <none>        8080:30751/TCP    21s
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing Target Port, Nodeport and Port.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49982009/9929015) you can find perfect explanation what the difference is.

Use nodePort instead of target-port. And more convenient way to expose your application is to create and apply yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-minikube
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: hello-minikube
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30006
  selector:
    run: hello-minikube
```

Comment: yaml file works, but I was wondering if its possible via kubeclt parameters

Comment: as I know - it is not possible